# Apache: Only respond to HTTPS-URLs on vhost with 443 binding

Tags: https, apache2, vhosts

I have 20+ vhosts listening on port 80 and a single one listening on port 443.

The 443 one is setup like this: `<VirtualHost secure.mywebsite.com:443>` but never the less, all other vhosts also respond to their domains with `https` in front of them... This results in https://myothersite.com to respond with the certificate of secure.mywebsite.com.

How do I avoid this?

I thought setting a specific domain would take care of the problem. I've searched the Googles to no avail and would really appreciate some help.